# How do I change the fields shown for participants on the CiviEvent Dashboard?

Tags: civievent, profile, smarty

I'd like to add one of the fields of the contacts in the list of participants shown on the CiviEvent Dashboard.

How would I do that? I'm sure it has something to do with the Smarty templating, so maybe I need a gentle introduction to that...

I'm running CiviCRM 4.7.7 but believe this would be the same for most recent versions.

Comment: Can you add what Civi version and CMS  are you using? With add fields, do you mean extra columns that show up next to the name, ie Current Employer?

Comment: I've added Civi version, but how do you think CMS would matter?

Comment: It matters, there are some tools/extensions that are available for Drupal and not for Wordpress/Joomla and viceversa. I'm not a Drupal user but I know that perhaps you could solve your requirements with Drupal Views without having to create an extension.

Comment: Are you saying that the builtin dashboard lists can be modified with non-civicrm tools? I would have thought not. Can you explain how to do that in an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily ... you can create an extension to call  [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchColumns) to provide the extra data to the template, and then change the CRM/Event/Form/Selector.tpl template to display that data.

Note that will change the event dashboard and also the events tab of a contact and the results of Find Participants.